# como ler dados do MySQL com Python?

Tags: mysql, python

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro e vendas de produtos. Preciso ter acesso às unidades cadastradas para verificar quantas unidades ainda faltam ser vendidas(com cada venda eu vou diminuindo as unidades restantes).

Tenho uma tabela vendas que contém : id, descrição, preço, venda, dia, mês, unidades e outra cadastros que contém as mesmas coisas.

Utilizei esse código:

```
        cursor = banco.cursor()
        mudar_estoque = f"SELECT id from cadastros where id = {id_produto_vendido}"
        cursor.execute(mudar_estoque)
        banco.commit()
```

Estou usando a biblioteca MySQL.connector

-- > Consegui executar o comando, mas como posso pegar o dado obtido através dessa execução em uma variável?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método que você está querendo é o `fetchall()`

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

**UPDATE**: `rows` será como uma lista, que pode ser iterada conforme abaixo

```
for row in rows:
        print(row["CAMPO_AQUI"])   # Também pode usar o índice: row[0]
```

**Nota**: para o comando `SELECT` não é necessário o `banco.commit()`. Este somente será necessário para o `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `DELETE`

Veja o `fecthall` com mais detalhes na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o Paulo disse, você vai utilizar a função `rows = cursor.fetchall()`, e a partir daí basta varrer o array `rows` da seguinte forma:

```
for row in rows:
        print(row["id"])
```